# how to re/connect wifi using cli toos

Tags: wireless

```
root@x# dmesg | grep rename
[    3.127628] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
[    5.302161] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlx10feed2673c7: renamed from wlan0
```

wf=wlx10feed2673c7

```
root@x# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
country=au
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
        ssid="hi-fi"
        psk=#########
}
```

connected using cmd

```
root@x# wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i $wf


root@x# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlx10feed2673c7
allow-hotplug wlx10feed2673c7
iface wlx10feed2673c7 inet dhcp
```

is my /etc/network/interfaces is correct
what is standard process of connecting wifi and "auto connect in future" (eg, reboot or wifi  out of reange, then again in range)
???

or I have to use as it is?

```
auto wlan0
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

wifi connected ok, but i want auto connect , on boot, on signal in range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal)

Comment: try "nmcli dev wifi con wlan0 password passwd123"

Comment: You could adapt my `bash script`: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.